# Crystal Report 11 hangs on Launch

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I launch the crystal Report software but it hangs with a busy cursor and does not return back to normal state. But if I turn of my internet connection and re launch, then it works just fine. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing happen today.  My guess is there is an issue with the update server.  Get Crystal to Launch by disabling your network, and then under Help, uncheck the Check for Updates on Startup.

Everything started working for me as normal after that even with my network turned on.